# Javascript calculates float value wrong

Tags: javascript, math

When I try to calculate a simple float value, I get the wrong result:

```
var a = 0.1111;
var b = 1 * 100;
alert(b); // Returns 11.110000000000001
```

Why it happens is discussed at [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), but how can you get around this problem in javacript?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc0805mt/1/

Answer (score 1):

This help you :

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
       <script>
           var a = 0.1111;
           var b = ((a*10000)*100)/10000;
           alert(b);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```